# MobX map of map

Tags: javascript, mobx

How do I make a map/transform of an `observable.map()`?

For example if I have an `observable.map()` of `Todos`, with their `id`s being the key:

```
var Todos = observable.map({
    'rf8r4': {id: 'rf8r4', description: 'Get milk'},
    '543w4': {id: '543w4', description: 'Code in MobX'},
    '099i0': {id: '099i0', description: 'Sleep'}
})
```

how can I automatically produce a UI state `observable.map()`, like for example containing a `visible` property defaulting to `true` (notice the keys correspond to those of the `Todos` above):

```
ui_state = observable.map({
    'rf8r4': {visible: true}, // defaults
    '543w4': {visible: false}, // changed to false after some user interaction
    '099i0': {visible: true}
})
```

but make sure that each Todo's state stays consistent after changes to the original `Todos` map, such as:

```
Todos.set('grtg6', {id: 'grtg6', description: 'Read StackOverflow'})
```

should result in (notice how `543w4`'s `visible` property is still `false`):

```
ui_state = observable.map({
    'rf8r4': {visible: true},
    '543w4': {visible: false},
    '099i0': {visible: true},
    'grtg6': {visible: true} // this is the new one
})
```

I tried `autorun`/`createTransformer`, but then it gets updated last as if it's a side-effect so I can't use `ui_state` in a React component.

I also tried different versions of `computed`, but it creates a new `ui_state` every time, because if I use `createTransformer` within the `computed` function, I get an error...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I figured out the best way to make a constantly-updated map of a `map`. See the [MobX Documentation on createTransformer](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/create-transformer.html).

I mentioned in the question that I tried `createTransformer` and was running into problems. This is because `autorun` is for running side-effects, and therefore it runs after all MobX data is updated. This means that if some MobX data (say, 'X') depends on both the `map` and the map of the `map`, then when the `map` is updated, then 'X' is updated, but X's other dependency, the map of the map, is stale, as the `autorun` hasn't run yet, and the resulting value of 'X' will either be wrong or the calculation itself will yield an error. Once the `autorun` finally runs and updates the map of the `map`, then 'X' has to be updated again.

The solution is to make 'X' *only* depend on the map of the `map`, and simply store a reference the entry in the original `map` in this map of `map`.

index.js:

```
import Inferno from 'inferno'
import { Provider } from 'inferno-mobx'
import h from 'inferno-hyperscript';

// Components:
import App from './inferno_components/App.js';

// Stores:
import languages from './stores/LanguagesStore.js';
import ui_state from './stores/LanguageViewState.js';


Inferno.render(
    h(Provider, {languages, ui_state}, // the following argument can't be an Array:
        h(App)
        )
, document.getElementById('main'));



// Make random changes post-render to make sure it re-renders:
languages.set('french', {id: 'french', example: 'Bonjour tout le monde'}); // map already passes the second arg through observable, so we don't need to do it explicitly
languages.get('french').example = 'Merci boucoup';

languages.set('german', {id: 'german', example: 'Gutten tag'});
languages.set('swahili', {id: 'swahili', example: 'Rafiki'});
languages.delete('german');


ui_state.get('english').visible = false;
```

components/App.js:

```
// for any component:
import { connect } from 'inferno-mobx'
import h from 'inferno-hyperscript';

// components to be used in this component:
import LanguageView from './LanguageView.js';


// the App:
var App = connect(['ui_state'], function({ui_state}){
    return h('div', ui_state.keys().map((language_name) => {
            var state = ui_state.get(language_name);
            if(state.visible) 
                return h(LanguageView, {language: state.language}); 
            else
                return h('p', 'Sorry, invisible!');
            }))
    });

export default App;
```

components/LanguageView.js:

```
import { connect } from 'inferno-mobx'
import h from 'inferno-hyperscript';


var LanguageView = connect(function({language}){
    return h('div', [
        h('p', language.id),
        h('p', language.example)
        ]);
    });

export default LanguageView;
```

stores/LanguagesStore.js:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx'

const languages = observable.map({
    english: {
        id: 'english',
        example: 'Hello World'
        }
    });

export default languages;
```

stores/LanguageViewState.js:

```
import { observable, createTransformer, intercept } from 'mobx';

import languages from './LanguagesStore.js';


const makeUIStateFromLanguage = createTransformer((language) => {
    return {language, visible: true}
    });


var ui_state = observable.map({});

// initialize:
languages.forEach((language, language_name) => {
    ui_state.set(language_name, makeUIStateFromLanguage(language));
    });

// set up automatic updating:
intercept(languages, function(change_object){
    if(change_object.type === 'add'){
        ui_state.set(change_object.name, makeUIStateFromLanguage(change_object.newValue));
        }
    else if(change_object.type === 'delete'){
        ui_state.delete(change_object.name);
        }
    return change_object; // for intercept
    });

export default ui_state;
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be difficult to add an entry to your ui map when you add a new entry in your state, but if you view entries not in the ui map as visible, you could do it [**like this**](http://jsbin.com/nosuqalire/1/edit?js,output):

```
const state = observable.map({
  'rf8r4': {id: 'rf8r4', description: 'Get milk'},
  '543w4': {id: '543w4', description: 'Code in MobX'},
  '099i0': {id: '099i0', description: 'Sleep'}
});

@observer
class App extends React.Component {
  @observable visible = asMap({
    'rf8r4': {visible: false}
  });
  @computed get visibleState() {
    const res = [];
    state.forEach(val => {
      const item = this.visible.get(val.id);
      if (!item || item.visible) {
        res.push(val);
      }
    });
    return res;
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.visibleState.map(el => 
        <div key={el.id} onClick={this.onClick}> {el.description} </div>
      )}
    </div>;
  }
  onClick = () => {
    this.visible.set('rf8r4', {visible: true});
  };
}
```

Comment: So I make a UIState map, and it only contains whatever was put into it explicitly. When I query the map, then if I find the proper entry, good, if not, I'll just use the default value for the UI property I'm trying to use (e.g. `visible = true` or `color = 'green'`). But, if entries get removed from the state map (i.e. `Todos`), and it has an entry in the UI map, that entry in the UI map stays, which over time may eat up memory?

Comment: @user1657586 That's a good point. If you have a long running application and tons of e.g. `Todos`, it might not be suitable.